# django ecommerce project geting this error AttributeError at /cart/ 'Order' object has no attribute 'orderitem_set'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get the orderitem per order. The error AttributeError at /cart/ 'Order' object has no attribute 'orderitem_set'

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank= True ,null = True)
    date_order = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True , blank=False)
    teansaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in orderitems])
        return total
    
    @property
    def get_cart_items(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
        return total
```

views.py

```
def cart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer = customer ,complete = False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total':0,'get_cart_items':0}
        
    context = {'items':items , 'order': order}
    return render(request,'store/cart.html',context)
```

Comment: Please add the orderitem model

Answer (score 1):

you should add "**get_cart_item**" in your  model(Order)

```
@property
def get_cart_items(self):
    orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
    total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
    return total
```

So, finally change your order model like this :-

class Order(models.Model):
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
    
@property
def shipping(self):
    shipping = False
    orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
    for i in orderitems:
        if i.product.digital == False:
            shipping = True
    return shipping

@property
def get_cart_total(self):
    orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
    total = sum([item.get_total for item in orderitems])
    return total
```